# Alguém pode explicar o motivo do bloqueio?

Tags: debate

Qual foi o motivo de ter sido bloqueado no chat?

Tomei alguns negativos e fiz um comentário com o @Bacco

> Esse usuário terá o fim como o outro

No sentido de quem estava me dando negativos em sequência anteriormente acabou sendo removido do site e acabou que isso não deu eu nada (pois os votos negativos foram removidos).

Agora gostaria de saber qual foi o tipo de coisa "Inapropriada" que eu falei (já que as minhas sinalizações também estão bloqueadas, preferi perguntar aqui).

Comment: Quero ver a moderação escapar dessa. =D

Comment: Na verdade não tenho nada a reclamar da moderação, mas quero saber o motivo. É claro que se passar os 30 minutos de bloqueio e ninguém dar uma explicação, e ficar por isso mesmo, realmente não vou pensar algo muito positivo.

Comment: Com certeza deve ter um motivo, algo que você não viu, mas eles viram. A moderação sempre fez um bom trabalho, vamos ver se eles dão alguma informação.

Comment: Lembrando que muito do sistema é automático

Comment: @Bacco como vou saber se é automático? Já tomei flags e não me deram mute. Se fosse automático, não seria todas as vezes bloqueado?

Comment: Talvez depois de determinada qtd de flags, não sei. Mas é só um palpite. O importante agora é: Lay low!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fui eu que apaguei. O teu comentário no chat foi

```
Esse usuário terá um fim igual o outro
```

e alguém se sentiu incomodado e lançou a flag para um moderador analisar.

No caso de ter sido a pessoa que votou negativamente isso pode ter sido tomado como ameaça, que votar negativo nas tuas perguntas ou respostas tem consequências.

Independentemente de estar de acordo ou não com o utilizador que possa ter votado, votar é um direito e enquanto não houver má fé com provas tenho de concordar com o utilizador que levantou a flag, que é ofensivo (ou pelo menos que tem tom de ameaça).

Se tiveres dúvidas sobre a intenção dos votos podes sempre avisar um moderador via flags de moderação.

Comment: Comentar sobre o voto também é um direito, não? Agora é aquele velho problema: Se qualquer um se sentir ameaçado, então eu serei bloqueado.

Comment: Eu avisaria sobre os votos se minhas flags não estivessem bloqueadas,  mas agora tenho que esperar 7 dias :D

Comment: Sergio, de qualquer forma, obrigado por ter dado um parecer. Moderação ativa no domingo :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters moderação 24/7, agora somos 6 :P Mas brincadeira à parte: sim, comentar sobre votos é um direito. Esse direito acaba quando outros se sentem ameaçados. O nosso papel é de moderar isso o melhor que podemos.

Comment: Estou ferrado então toda vez que alguém se sentir ameaçado. Na verdade, o eu não vou matar, nem prejudicar ninguém. Estou falando do que aconteceu antes: "Quem estava fazendo atividades irregulares foi excluído, os votos negativos sumiram, e não deu em nada".

Comment: De qualquer maneira, já se passaram os 30 minutos

Comment: Bacana, se aqui fosse o "reclame aqui", eu marcaria como "Satisfeito"

Comment: _"Estou ferrado então toda vez que alguém se sentir ameaçado."_ - cada caso é único e será avaliado como tal. Eventuais casos anteriores que tenha sido concluído que foram votos visados não se pode automáticamente assumir que é o que aconteceu agora porque recebeste 2 votos negativos. Se tens duvidas avisa os moderadores. Dizer no chat _"Esse usuário terá um fim igual o outro"_ pode magoar.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters tu até podes não ter tido a intenção de ameaçar ninguém, mas a verdade é que o teu comentário parece ameaçador, assim fora do contexto... A minha primeira impressão antes de ler a tua explicação é que era ameaçador mesmo. Vá não leves a mal que é mesmo assim que o site (e chat) funciona.

Comment: @JorgeB. já foi tudo esclarecido.